# How to extract the unmatched portion of a string using a regex

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

I'm trying to display some messages to the user when the input is invalid.

I wrote this regex, to validade this pattern : (Name of 10 characters) (Number between 0-9)

e.g. Bruno 3

```
^([\w]{1,10})(\s[\d]{1})$
```

When the user input any invalid string, Is it possible to know what group is invalid and print a message?
Something like that:

```
if (regex_match(user_input, e))
{
  cout << "input ok" << endl;
}
else
{
    if (group1 is invalid)
    {
        cout << "The name must have length less than 10 characters" << endl;
    }

    if (group2 is invalid)
    {
        cout << "The command must be between 0 - 9" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `[\d]{1}` can just be `\d`

Comment: What code did you come up with and what is wrong with it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the question

Comment: what is the length of you input string

Comment: Since there is no built-in feature to know what part of a regex failed, you can only workaround it with 2 `regex_search`es, one with `^\w{1,10}` and the second one with `\s\d$` regexps.

Comment: Often the best regular expression is the one you don't use. It only takes about four lines of code to write this test directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you want to match `1 to 10 character` then a single `space` and then a single `digit`  but in 2 **group**

here is what you want:

## [`^([a-zA-Z]{1,10})( \d)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cAJFDk/4)

**NOTE**

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
So if you need only 10 characters you should use `[a-zA-Z]` not `\w`

---

**C++ code**

```
std::string string( "abcdABCDxy 9" );

std::basic_regex< char > regex( "^([a-zA-Z]{1,10})( \\d)$" );
std::match_results< std::string::const_iterator > m_result;

std::regex_match( string, m_result, regex );
std::cout << m_result[ 1 ] << '\n';   // group 1
std::cout << m_result[ 2 ] << '\n';   // group 2
```

**the output**

```
1abcdABCDxy
 9
```